# Firefox for Android not downloading file using window.location

Tags: javascript, android, firefox

I'm trying to make a script where when you click a button, you're redirected to a downloadable file. Firefox on Android is the ONLY browser that does this. And when I say only, I mean that:

On my desktop:

- IE5, 7, 8, 9, 10, and 11
- FF
- Chrome
- Opera
- Safari

On my tablet:

- Baidu Browser
- Boat Browser
- Stock ICS Browser
- Chrome
- Chrome Beta
- Dolphin Browser
- Next Browser
- Opera
- Opera Beta
- Opera Mini
- UC Browser

ALL of those work. I've even tired doing a remote debug, and manually using the console to redirect to the file to download, but all it does it refresh the page. However, if I manually type in the URL, it does download.

Can anybody provide any insight on this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

[Page Deleted]

It looks like a direct address no longer works. The output on either link, or a direct address is:

> GET [URL] [HTTP/1.1 200
>   OK]

Comment: What does happen on FF mobile? (you don't say other than it "doesn't work"). Can you test it on your own device? (using MS Excel document as an example....) does the 'download' URL you forward to set the appropriate MIME type (e.g: `Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel` header) for the content being served? Does the 'download' URL set the appropriate disposition? (e.g: `Content-disposition: attachment; filename="name_of_excel_file.xls"`).

Comment: Nothing. I just see the loading bar go across. The console shows the file being requested with a HTTP 200 response, but I get no download. And I'm just going straight to a raw mp3 file, so I would assume the browser would take care of the header like all the others.

Comment: I've added a link and what I'm getting to the original post

Comment: You assume wrong about the browser taking care of the download (or manufacturing the headers on your behalf if that's what you meant). If you want the file be 'downloaded' to the client, you (on the _server_ side) need to, at least, set the `Content-disposition: attachment`. Otherwise, what happens is completely user-agent dependent.

Comment: BTW: Given you haven't arranged for the file to be downloaded by the client, most likely scenario is that FF on Android is trying to play the MP3, or asking Android OS to play it.

Comment: Here is the HTTP reponse headers your server is returning (for me on FF desktop v26): http://pastebin.com/aUyZGWF6 You're definitely leaving it to chance as to how the client will handle this content.

Comment: So you're telling me I have to tell it how to download? Because currently, I don't care how it downloads, just as long as it does. As in, whether it's saved, or tried to be played by FF, or by Android, I don't care. What baffles me is that nothing is happening. No download, no dialog, no anything. Just a GET request, and then that seems to be the end of that.

Comment: No. The server must specify (via `Content-disposition: attachment` header) only THAT it must be downloaded (rather than displayed inline). It doesn't specify HOW that occurs on the client (i.e: whether the browser then prompts the user where to save it, or does a security dialog, or something else).

Comment: Think of the HTTP response like an SMTP email message. If you have some binary object (say an image), you could either put it in the email body (`Content-disposition: inline`) or as an attachment (`Content-disposition: attachment; filename="..."`). Traditionally, the browser (much like Outlook/Thunderbird/etc) DISPLAYS "inline" binaries (e.g: images), and asks you to SAVE "attachment" binaries.

Comment: Yes, but what if I don't care whether or not the image is displayed inline, or as an attachment? I just want to somehow get it to the user.

Comment: `get it to the user`. That's pretty meaningless, especially on mobile. Basically, you've asked a question that can't be answered in a general way. I've given you a suggestion to try that specifically deals with the issue of 'downloading' it to the client -- which is what you said you wanted. You don't want to try it. Amazing.

Comment: No, I'm willing to try it, and I appreciate your help, I just think it's ridiculous that 22 other browsers can manage without. Furthermore, if I do that, now I my HTML5 audio players won't work, which means now I have to have a script that distinguishes whether or not to push a stream or a download. Thankfully, I was already planning on that, but still, 22 other browsers can do it right. Either way, you're not the developer, so pointless complaining to you. Forcing an octet-stream does work. Did you want to put your answer into a real answer so you can get credit for it?

Comment: Honestly, it's a near duplicate of 20+ existing language-specific questions, either answered either correctly by `Content-disposition` or by`Content-type` hacks. Better to close/remove the question. I only entered this discussion to get you to do some actual debugging in case it wasn't going to be the standard `Content-disposition` solution.

Comment: Understandable, and I could do that, but then where would the next guy go that's looking for why 1/23 browsers is acting differently? I did try searching for this before finally just asking, because I couldn't find anything that related to my question.

Comment: If the goal is to ask that the browser download the file, rather than attempt to display it inline, the method I gave you works for ALL browsers, on any platform, since 1996ish.

Comment: The goal was to get Firefox to do something with it. Either way, if you don't want the points for solving a question, then so be it.

Comment: If the goal is to get Firefox (or any other browser) to "do something" with it  (rather than download it), then you should set the `Content-type:` header and avoid setting the `Content-disposition:` header. Then it's down to the individual browser as to whether it knows what to do with the MIME-type you supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you have to use the server to force the download, because FF for Android acts differently than every other browser. I'd like to have a better answer, but essentially, you just have to deal with that behavior.

You can learn more by reading the full discussion under the original post.

Comment: You should edit the relevant part of the discussion into this answer.